# Trying to understand Callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm creating a simple callback function trying to understand how it works.

```
function cbFunction(x, y, z) {
  return x + y + z
}

function caller(x, y, z, cbFunction) {
  console.log('In caller function!')
  // your code here
  if (typeof cbFunction === "function") {
    cbFunction (x, y, z)
  }
}

caller(1, 2, 3, cbFunction)
```

I'm invoking the cbFunction inside the caller function. Could you help me to understand why it isn't adding x, y, z? I'm learning JS as a beginner and thank you for your help!

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't add the numbers? You're not doing anything with the result other than returning it and `caller` doesn't care about the return value either.

Comment: It actually is adding x, y and z, however you're not doing anything with the result of `cbFunction`, you could try `return cbFunction(x, y, z)`  in the caller functionthen `console.log(caller(1, 2, 3, cbFunction));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is adding the numbers - you just aren't doing anything with the result returned by `cbFunction`.

Instead, return the result returned by `cbFunction`:

```js
function cbFunction(x, y, z) {
  return x + y + z
}

function caller(x, y, z, cbFunction) {
  console.log('In caller function!')
  // your code here
  if (typeof cbFunction === "function") {
    return cbFunction(x, y, z); //<-- return
  }
}

console.log(caller(1, 2, 3, cbFunction))
```

Comment: I see it now. Thank you so much for the explanation!

Comment: Yeah, i tried but it asked me wait for a couple mins. I will.